# Get a list of all supported EPSG code from OGR

Tags: ogr, c++, epsg, documentation, user-interface

I need get a a list of all supported EPSG code from OGR/GDAL. I need this becaouse i'm developing a C++ application map, and I need this information to put it in a user form.

I read the OGR documentation but I couldn`t find any method to do this. Some one know how is possible get this information in OGR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have proj 6 installed, you can query the proj.db file to get the list of EPSG codes it supports. On my machine, the following works:

```
sqlite3 /usr/share/proj/proj.db "SELECT code FROM projected_crs WHERE auth_name = 'EPSG';"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reference [the EPSG Dataset](http://www.epsg.org/) maintainted by the International Association of Oil & Gas Producers (IOCP)

> The IOGP’s EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset is a collection of definitions of coordinate reference systems and coordinate transformations which may be global, regional, national or local in application.
>
> The primary EPSG Dataset is maintained in the online registry, from which data may be accessed through a graphic user interface or through a service interface. The online registry contains the most current data. Registry users may query and view the data, generate printable reports and create Well-known Text (WKT) compliant with ISO 19162. The online registry supports anonymous (guest) access, but also permits the user to register for additional services, such as the export of the entire Dataset.
>
> Approximately twice a year snapshots of this data are also made available through MS Access files downloadable from here.  Area polygons are downloadable as a Shapefile. To download these files them you need to log in (requires having previously registered) and then go to the Download Dataset section. The Registry GML schema files are also available there.
>
> The EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset is maintained by the Geodesy Subcommittee of the IOGP Geomatics Committee. For more information about the Geomatics Committee please visit http://www.iogp.org/geomatics or contact the Geomatics Committee Manager at lks@iogp.org.
>   About registration